# Python - Classification Lasso sklearn - How to predict classes

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification

Following the example:
http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.Lasso.html

```
from sklearn import linear_model
clf = linear_model.Lasso(alpha=0.1)
clf.fit([[0,0], [1, 1], [2, 2]], [0, 1, 2])

clf.predict(np.array([0,0]).reshape(1,-1))
Out[13]: array([ 0.15])
```

Can I get the prediction to be a classification instead of a regression. In other words when I give it an input, I would like an output that is categorical.

Comment: Can't you just add some "if" statements after your regression? Most classifiers are based on dividing the space into subspaces in order to labelise them. Basicly it's only adding "if" statements after mapping your data into the wanted space (usually one that permits a linear classification).

Comment: I am really not sure sure. I thought maybe rounding?

Comment: You can use sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression model with 'l1' penalty.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `LogisticRegression` with `penalty='l1'`.
It is, essentially, the Lasso regression, but with the additional layer of converting the scores for classes to the "winning" class output label.
Regularization strength is defined by `C`, which is the INVERSE of `alpha`, used by `Lasso`.
Scikit-learn has a very nice brief overview of linear models:
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/linear_model.html

Comment: I believe `penalty='l2'` *does not* lead to Lasso regression. It's ridge regression/classification. One wants to specify `penalty='l1'` instead.

Comment: Yes, @diadochos, you are right - LASSO (least absolute shrinkage and selection operator) uses the `'l1'` norm of the weight vector. `'l2'` is for Ridge/Tikhonov regularization. My slip up. Thank you for pointing it out. Answer corrected.

Answer (score -3):

You can use Lasso and sort prediction results in descending way, so the first 50% will be 1 and the last are 0.